# select date sql opposite DATE PHP ECHO JSON

Tags: php, json, date-format

**after SELECT** information from server,
i'm Getting Date Formate as **YYYY / MM / DD**.
i'm trying opposite the date to **DD / MM / YYYY**

the information must to be **echo** in **JSON** array.

can you help me opposite the date?
here's my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Shows WHERE ID ='{$ID}' ORDER BY date ASC");

$users = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))    
    {

    $users[] = array('date' => $row['date'],'day' => $row['day'],'hour' => $row['hour']);

    }

    echo json_encode($users);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `$users` declaration to:

```
$users[] = array('date' => date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row['date']) )
```